# Javascript JSON formatting equivalent in Python

Tags: javascript, python

I need to format something in this exact JSON format:

```
JSON.stringify(data,null,'\t');
```

How would I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3:

```
import json

json.dumps(data, indent='\t')
```

If you're using Python 2 or need to support both versions, use the `simplejson` module:

```
import simplejson as json
```

The builtin `json` module in Python 2 indents only with spaces.

Comment: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"

Comment: @GabiPurcaru: You're using Python 2. `import simplejson as json` instead.

Comment: You can still indent, just not with `\t` tabs. `indent=4` will use 4 spaces instead of a tab.